# Autoformat code in a jupyter notebook with a keystroke

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a widget or keyboard shortcut to apply code formatting a jupyter notebook?

If I have a function like:

```py
def f(x):
y = x*2
z = y*2
return z
```

I'd like to be able to autotab this function over to:

```py
def f(x):
    y = x*2
    z = y *2
    return z
```

automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [Jupyter Nbextensions Configurator](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/tree/master/src/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/static/nbextensions_configurator) which contains several extensions for your Jupiter Notebook needs:

1. [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8);
2. [Code prettify](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/code_prettify/README_code_prettify.html).

You'll find instructions on how to set them up in links.
Both of extensions have their settable toolbar buttons and are applicable to a whole document.

Comment: Code prettify is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There's [jupyter-black](https://github.com/n8henrie/jupyter-black) - a simple extension for Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab to beautify Python code automatically using Black

For JupyterLab, there's also [JupyterLab_Black](https://github.com/ryantam626/jupyterlab_black).

For JupyterLab, there's [jupyterlab_code_formatter](https://github.com/ryantam626/jupyterlab_code_formatter) - a JupyterLab plugin to facilitate invocation of code formatters. You can configure the keyboard shortcut for that.

---

Keep in mind that soon (present is Fall 2022) the document-centric notebook experience, most people now associate with the classic notebook interface, will be based on what is underlying JupyterLab, see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html). And thus investing great time working out things in the old classic notebook may result in you needing to change approaches soon as a lot of the stuff that works only with the classic Jupyter notebook interface will need updating to use while things already working in current JupyterLab will either work or have a lot less friction getting updated.

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar with the document-centric notebook experience you're describing.  Is there a move to obsolete jupyter in favor of something else?  What should I read to understand what you're talking about?

Comment: If you go to [the Jupyter page](https://jupyter.org/)  now &scroll down, first you'll see 'JupyterLab: A Next-Generation Notebook Interface'. Then below that is: 'Jupyter Notebook: The Classic Notebook Interface'.  That last one is the 'document-centric experience' as stated [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html). Usually called the 'classic notebook interface'. However, since the newer version of it will be based on different tech, the 'classic' nature is misleading. Hence empahasis on the document-centric nature. There's no move to obsolete Jupyter.

Comment: I should have also mentioned [this Jupyter blog post 'Jupyter Notebook 6.5.0 Release Candidate'](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-6-5-0-release-candidate-4c229c6dab55), which covers the  the NbClassic project in context, relative JupyterLab and Notebook 7.